# how to get a hover effect with jQuery?? Its not working for me

Tags: jquery-hover

I'm trying to get hover effect similar to this [example](http://www.incg.nl/blog/2008/hover-block-jquery/example/animate_hover.html). But couldn't get it. Here is the [link](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/hovereffect.html)

Comment: I think you have to ask something more specific.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @Xint0 -- http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/YZzWu/2/

Comment: @MikeEast -- When I move the mouseover the image nothing is happening.

Comment: I changed the image path.  Still its not working..Any insight??

Comment: Its working but not as expected..the img on top is sliding below the source img and is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On test page this is your css:

```
.thumb {
list-style: none;
float: left;
background: white;
width: 250px;
position: relative;/* this makes all the difference */
}
```

On production page:

```
.project .thumb {
width: 260px;
float: left;
}
```

Add `position: relative` to `.project .thumb`

Answer (score 2):

Your `<script>` tag references a `jquery-1.2.6.min.js` which does not exist. Put that file in the same directory as `hovereffect.html` on your web server.

Or, perhaps even better, get JQuery from Google Libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Priya In other words, your javascript code is fine. The problem is that the page does not have the correct reference to jQuery source.

Comment: I was trying to modify a bit in my code. Instead of displaying images as list, I tried to place them in <div> tags. Its working fine dragonfly.zymichost.com/hovereffect2.html. But when I place them in my actual page for some reason its not working..dragonfly.zymichost.com/projects1.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the code copied to the new page is missing the position:relative, which would fix the issue. Now, for security, you may want to limit the height of the block and set the overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you are missing a css property

```
.project .thumb img {position:absolute}
```

notice that you have this line in your test page.

the way you are using jQuery's animate function to change the position of the top image {top:150px}, so you need make it absolutely position for this to work.

Also the `.project .thumb a line` is missing it's width and height.

Also note that if you just add that line, the affect still won't be the way you expect. Create an outer `div` with an `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify `height:150px;` on your outer class (`.outer`). Currently it's set to 250px which is too tall.

Answer (score 0):

Its because in your real project your css is in the /css directory.  So your CSS style is looking for /css/images/snbw_thumb.jpg which doesn't exist.  Change your CSS style to ../images/snbw_thumb.jpg and it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is 404ing due to your css rule for .project .thumb a{}
It points to "images/snbw_thumb.jpg" but you'll likely want to use "/images/snbw_thumb.jpg"

Bad URL : http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/css/images/snbw_thumb.jpg

Good URL : http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/images/snbw_thumb.jpg

(Also, it looks like your pages aren't really serving 404s as the bad URL )

Hope this helps

-Chris