# hover is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get a hover effect with jQuery?? Its not working for me..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345892/how-to-get-a-hover-effect-with-jquery-its-not-working-for-me)

I was trying to modify a bit in my code. Instead of displaying images as list, I tried to place them in  tags. Its working fine [dragonfly.zymichost.com/hovereffect2.html](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/hovereffect2.html). But when I place them in my actual page for some reason its not working as expected. [dragonfly.zymichost.com/projects1.html](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/projects1.html)